# Bootstrap move navbar below other divs on large screens

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am building a responsive page using bootstrap 3.1.1 and I would like to move the navbar so that it is below some other divs when viewed on non-smartphone screens. See the image below for an example.

[image: Intended layout]

I've attempted to do this using the bootstrap pull/push classes (see code) but I can't seem to get the combination right. It is displaying as I intend for smartphone, but not larger devices.

http://www.bootply.com/118321

**HTML**

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-push-12">
        <div class="navbar navbar-inverse" role="navigation">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>
                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Project name</a>
                </div>
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                        <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="container">
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-pull-12">
            <h1>First Title Heading</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-pull-12">
            <h1>Second Title Heading</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: If you can modify your html then you may include the bottom navigation too (clone it). And then - simply hide/show the top or the bottom nav when needed. I seriously doubt you can achieve the desired effect with your current markup.

Answer (score 1):

It can be easily done using jQuery. Have two `div`s, one at the top and another at the bottom. Now, when you have a large screen size, give the html of the navbar to the above `div` and to the bottom one if the screen size is small.

Here's what it would look like:

```
if (screenSize > 1280px) $(#topnav).html('Your navbar HTML here');
else $(#bottomnav).html('Your navbar HTML here');
```

where `topnav` and `bottomnav` are the two `div`s. 
The only thing you now need to figure out is how to get the screen size. Here's how it can be done:

```
$(window).resize(function(){
 var screenSize = $(window).width();
});
```

Now just insert your HTML in there and it should work.

Comment: This is a good suggestion. I would prefer to use the bootstrap grid system if possible, but unless someone can indicate how that would work I will take the JQuery approach.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use 'pull' to put your element in the left and top and 'push' to put it on the right and bottom. So you're using these classes in the wrong way. invert the two and it will work !